# How to fit various length cuts of lumber into standard length lumber piece

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the most efficient way to cut some small pieces of lumber from a standard 2" by 4" by 8' piece. I'm having trouble searching up the algorithm used for this. Please help! I use Python but just want to get the general idea of how an algorithm would work.

The situation is, I need to make some cuts of lumber that are shorter than 8', and are different in length. I want to cut the short lumber in from the smallest number of 8' pieces available. The pieces I need are:

- 3* 34"
- 2* 25"
- 2* 30"
- 2* 39"

My thoughts so far:
Method 1: set the shortest length as the base, and try to fit the longest length of lumber into the first original 2by4. as soon as the leftover is smaller than the shortest, remove the pieces used in the first calculation and add the number of 2by4 needed by 1. Repeat until all pieces are used.
Problem with this one is there is no way to prove this gives the most efficient cut. It could be that a  different arrangement of pieces would save a 2by4 altogether.

Any idea is appreciated.

Edit: This is a real problem I have with trying to design a winter tire rack from lumber. In Canada and the States, lumber come in 2"by4"by8' pieces, so given the number of pieces I need to build the rack and their length, I want to optimize the number of 2by4s I have to buy. Let's call the pieces I want 'pieces' and the 2by4by8 'standard'.

My method 1 above is basically the brute force idea. i.e. A queue is formed with the pieces in them, then I try to fit as many pieces into a standard as I can, removing the 'used' pieces from the queue, and quit when the leftover length in the standard is shorter than my shortest piece left, and add 1 to the number of standards I need. This will provide a reasonably efficient solution and would suffice for my purposes, as lumber is not that expensive after all. Thinking about this issue got me thinking tho: what if the lumber was expensive, or if I get this question in an coding interview,

How do we mathematically or algorithmically prove one solution is the most efficient solution? I'm taking whichever piece that fits into the leftover standard, so there's no math proof that the solution is the most efficient. Say the pieces we need are categorized into long, medium, and short lengths, even if we sort the original pieces queue in order of large to small, and start fitting the longest pieces into standard before the shorter ones, there could still be a case where the standard can be used by

long, medium, waste
medium, medium, short, waste,
short, waste
which takes 3 standards and causes a huge waste by the third standard only used by one short,

as opposed to:
long, short, short, waste
medium, medium, medium, waste,
which takes 2 standards and the waste are minimized.

Again, question is, is there a way to prove mathematically that a solution, or a set of solutions, is/are the most efficient in terms of minimized waste?

Thanks to the answers so far, they are the brute force solutions I had above. Please keep the proofs coming :)

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve in the first case. Can you reformulate your problem?

Comment: Sounds like the cutting stock problem: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem

Comment: Are you saying you want up to 3 pieces of 34" lumber, up to 2 pieces of 25" lumber, etc., and you want to but the 8' lumber into pieces so that each resulting cut piece comes from that list except for one, and you want that one last piece to be as small as possible? Your question is not clear.

Comment: `1*39`, `1*30+1*39`, `1*34+1*30+1*25`, `2*34+1*25` is 4 pieces. It's not possible to do it in 3 pieces because 3*8' is 288" and the sum of lengths you want is 290".

Comment: You'd probably get more answers if using metric units. " and ' are seconds and minutes, for what i know (as being scandinavian). You talk about inches and feet? The 2x4" is a well known dimension to me, though i believe it's pretty much set to 50x100 mm. Inches and feet are a pain and it is no point arguing that they wouldn't be :-).

Comment: I'm aware this particular problem takes at least 4 pieces. Please see my edit for the updated question, which is: Is there a way to prove any solution is the most efficient?

Answer (score 0):

This program solves the problem using the crudest of brute force. It enumerates all possible subsets of pieces for the first stick, and then recurses, keeping a cache of previous computations. With 9 target pieces, there's only 512 subsets, so this is entirely fast enough (as it completes instantaneously).

```
def one_stick(pieces, stick_len):
    if not pieces:
        yield (), ()
        return
    size, n = pieces[0]
    for i in xrange(n + 1):
        if size * i > stick_len:
            break
        for s, r in one_stick(pieces[1:], stick_len - size * i):
            if i < n:
                r = ((size, n - i),) + r
            if i > 0:
                s = ((size, i),) + s
            yield s, r

def sticks(pieces, stick_len, cache):
    if not pieces:
        return 0, ()
    if sum(size * n for n, size in pieces) <= stick_len:
        return 1, (pieces,)
    if pieces not in cache:
        best = 1000, []
        for s1, remainder in one_stick(pieces, stick_len):
            if not s1:
                continue
            bv, bs = sticks(remainder, stick_len, cache)
            if bv + 1 < best[0]:
                best = bv + 1, (s1,) + bs
        cache[pieces] = best
    return cache[pieces]

pieces = ((34, 3), (25, 2), (30, 2), (39, 2))
bv, bs = sticks(pieces, 8 * 12, {})
print bv
for stick in bs:
    print ' + '.join('%d*%d' % (n, size) for size, n in stick), ' \t(length = %d)' % sum(i * n for i, n in stick)
```

The program produces this output:

```
4
1*39    (length = 39)
1*30 + 1*39     (length = 69)
1*34 + 1*25 + 1*30      (length = 89)
2*34 + 1*25     (length = 93)
```

That is, you can use 4 pieces of 8' length. Even if you don't trust the program, this is provably optimal since the sum of lengths you want is 290" which is more than 3*8', so it's impossible to find a solution that uses 3 or fewer pieces.

If I wanted to improve this program, I'd start by improving `one_stick`. It could only yield maximal subsets of sticks rather than all subsets. That is, it would discard subsets that can have one or more additional sticks added (while keeping under the `stick_len` limit). This would reduce the amount of recursion done, and won't affect the size of the optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment! I've found a website that does this calculation, I asked on StackOverflow more to get the really mathy-side things out, which is proving that one/set of solution is the most optimal. Thanks for typing all this out!

Comment: In your question you asked for an algorithm, and labelled the question "python". But now you say you wanted some math and have changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this brutally, using the excellent parallel array processing language **[Dyalog APL](http://www.dyalog.com)**. The solution turned out to be rather surprising.

The task is 2-fold; on the other hand you want to minimise the spill amount but on the other hand you have a sequence to maintain:

3*34 + 2*25 + 2*30 + 2*39 = one chair? :-) (sorry, had written chair already - saw your edit though)

The sequence is a practical problem. If for example being a self-employed craftsman, one doesn't want to manufacture huge series in advance. There needs to be a start and end to the job, and one doesn't keep huge amounts of raw material at site. Hence one wants to have a reasonable "repetition" using a few 8' pieces, where one cycle ends up in 3-2-2-2 pieces (or a multiple of).

As [Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400793/paul-hankin) states, there exists no solution for 3 or less pieces of 8' raw material. The smallest series to use is 4 pieces, and the outcome is in that case:

1. There are 53 unique solutions
2. **Each solution produces a huge 94" of spill** (see later comment though)

This was the surprise (at least for me). No matter how you distribute the lenghts, the spill sits steadily at 94". **There exists no obvious way to optimise (minimise) the spill, since the whole operation is bound by the sequence 3-2-2-2**. If we optimise the spill amount, we end up with a different amount of short pieces (for example 400-200-200-200 after 100 chairs), meaning we'd have 100 extra pieces of 1st lenght, to no use.

The 53 possible solutions below. I have marked 1 of them with a star, as being the optimal choice, see comment below table.

We use 4 pieces of 8' (columns marked 1-4). For example the topmost row means that we cut 1*25" from the 1st long piece, 2*39" from the 2nd, 2*34 & 1*25 from the 3rd and 1*34" & 2*30" from the 4th. In alles we get the 3-2-2-2 pieces. The "Spills" column indicate how much spill we get per each 8' piece, followed by a total Σ.

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills     │Σ │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼──┤
│ 0 1 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 2 1 0 0 │ 1 0 2 0 │71 18  3  2│94│
│ 0 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │66 23  3  2│94│
│ 0 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 2 1 0 0 │66 18  7  3│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │ 0 1 1 1 │62 28  2  2│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │62 27  3  2│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │62 23  7  2│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 0 1 │ 1 0 2 0 │62 23  7  2│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 2 0 0 │ 1 0 2 0 │62 18 12  2│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 0 1 2 0 │ 2 1 0 0 │62 18 11  3│94│
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 1 1 1 0 │62 18  7  7│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │ 1 0 2 0 │57 32  3  2│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 2 1 0 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │57 32  3  2│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │57 28  7  2│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 2 0 1 │ 1 0 2 0 │57 28  7  2│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 2 1 0 0 │57 27  7  3│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │ 1 0 2 0 │57 23 12  2│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 1 2 0 │ 2 1 0 0 │57 23 11  3│94│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 1 1 1 0 │57 23  7  7│94│
│ 0 2 0 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 0 2 0 │46 28 18  2│94│
│ 0 2 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 2 0 │46 23 23  2│94│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 2 1 0 0 │41 32 18  3│94│ *
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 1 1 1 │41 28 23  2│94│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │41 28 18  7│94│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │41 27 23  3│94│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │41 23 23  7│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 1 1 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 0 2 0 │37 37 18  2│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 0 0 2 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 2 1 0 0 │37 36 18  3│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 2 0 │37 32 23  2│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 1 1 1 │37 32 23  2│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │37 32 18  7│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 1 1 1 │37 28 27  2│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 0 1 2 0 │37 28 18 11│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │37 27 27  3│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │37 27 23  7│94│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 1 2 0 │37 23 23 11│94│
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │36 32 23  3│94│
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 0 1 │36 28 23  7│94│
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 2 0 0 │36 28 18 12│94│
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │36 23 23 12│94│
│ 0 1 0 1 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 1 0 2 0 │32 32 28  2│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 1 1 1 │32 32 28  2│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 2 1 0 0 │32 32 27  3│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 1 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │32 32 23  7│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 0 1 │32 32 23  7│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 2 0 0 │32 32 18 12│94│
│ 0 1 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │32 28 27  7│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 2 0 1 │32 28 27  7│94│
│ 0 1 0 1 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 1 2 0 │32 28 23 11│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 0 2 1 0 │32 28 18 16│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │32 27 23 12│94│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │32 23 23 16│94│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │28 27 27 12│94│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │28 27 23 16│94│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──┘
```

The row marked with a star is obviously the optimum, since it contains two long rest pieces, 41" and 32". These two allow for any two of the short lenghts, meaning that for each chair (= 9 pieces), you get **2/9 chairs extra :-)**. Or reversed, for every 4.5th chair, you get one extra chair! Otoh, it also adds entirely new trouble to the problem: Some of the solutions "leak" usable raw material, that should be taken care of in future cycles. Which leaks qualify for what, when should they be consumed, ... whatnot :-).

As i had this small APL code sniplet handy, i also tried with other raw material lenghts. Some discoveries:

### 2 long pieces

Turns out that the minimum material lenght is ca 12.17'. We get the result below, and longer raw material doesn't seem to improve anything, because we simply consume 2*12.17' per chair (however we get more "leaked" material with even longer lenghts).

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────┐
│1        │2        │Spills   │Σ   │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────┤
│ 1 2 2 0 │ 2 0 0 2 │2.04 0.04│2.08│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────┘
```

### 3 long pieces

If you could extend the raw material with only ca 0.17', to 8.17', you'd get a **rather good** split:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬────┐
│1        │2        │3        │Spills        │Σ   │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼────┤
│ 0 1 1 1 │ 2 0 1 0 │ 1 1 0 1 │4.04 0.04 0.04│4.12│
│ 1 0 2 0 │ 1 1 0 1 │ 1 1 0 1 │4.04 0.04 0.04│4.12│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴────┘
```

Increasing raw material lenght increases the spill. 9.5' gives 32 uniques, first rows:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┬──┐
│1        │2        │3        │Spills  │Σ │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼──┤
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 2 │ 1 2 1 0 │50  2  0│52│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 2 │ 1 2 1 0 │46  6  0│52│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 2 2 0 │ 1 0 0 2 │46  4  2│52│
│ 0 0 1 1 │ 2 0 0 1 │ 1 2 1 0 │45  7  0│52│
│ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 1 1 │ 1 2 1 0 │41 11  0│52│
│ 1 0 0 1 │ 2 0 0 1 │ 0 2 2 0 │41  7  4│52│
```

### 4 long pieces

Turns out that if we have as short as 6.67', we get:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────────────┬─────┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills               │Σ    │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────────────────┼─────┤
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 0 2 1 0 │16.04 12.04 2.04 0.04│30.16│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │16.04  7.04 7.04 0.04│30.16│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │12.04 11.04 7.04 0.04│30.16│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────────────┴─────┘
```

This seems to be the minimum for 4 cycles.

With 7' we get:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬──┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills    │Σ │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──┤
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 2 0 0 │24 16  6 0│46│
│ 0 0 2 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │24 11 11 0│46│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 2 0 0 │20 20  6 0│46│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 0 2 1 0 │20 16  6 4│46│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │20 15 11 0│46│
│ 1 0 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │20 11 11 4│46│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │16 15 15 0│46│
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │16 15 11 4│46│
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴──┘
```

With 7.5':

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills     │Σ │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼──┤
│ 1 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 1 1 1 0 │56 12  1  1│70│
│ 0 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │ 1 1 1 0 │51 17  1  1│70│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │35 22 12  1│70│
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 1 1 1 0 │35 17 17  1│70│
│ 1 1 0 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 1 1 1 0 │31 26 12  1│70│
(ca 20 more rows)
```

9' gives 229 uniques:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────────┬───┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills      │Σ  │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────────┼───┤
│ 0 0 0 0 │ 0 2 1 0 │ 3 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 2 │108 28  6  0│ 34│ <- Note, this is a 3-cycle result
│ 0 0 0 0 │ 0 2 1 0 │ 1 0 1 1 │ 2 0 0 1 │108 28  5  1│ 34│ <- Ditto
│ 0 0 0 0 │ 1 2 0 0 │ 2 0 1 0 │ 0 0 1 2 │108 24 10  0│ 34│ <- Ditto
 (scrapped rows)
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 2 0 0 │ 40 39 39 24│142│ *
│ 2 0 0 0 │ 0 0 1 1 │ 1 0 0 1 │ 0 2 1 0 │ 40 39 35 28│142│ *
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────────┴───┘
```

Further 4-cycle results seem to increase the spill (and create more "leaks")

### Conclusion

Ignoring the experimental lenghts above and focusing on the original parameters, the optimal solution for cycles of 3 long pieces seems to be

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──┐
│1        │2        │3        │4        │Spills     │Σ │
├─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼───────────┼──┤
│ 0 1 1 0 │ 1 0 1 0 │ 0 0 0 2 │ 2 1 0 0 │41 32 18  3│94│ *
```

since we can further use the leaked material. However, it is possible that we could begin to focus on multiples of the original sequence 3-2-2-2 together with higher cycle lengths. And i have no idea what happens then :-). This is probably a **never-ending scenario**.

The "leaked material" makes this a recursive thingy, which feel spractically impossible to solve, at least without further constraints. When to re-use it? In 3 cycles, in 22 cycles? How many "sets of leaked material" do you have simultaneously, in what order do you use it? Hehe... you have a lifetime to use?

It is probably possible to resolve the "minimum lenghts" - the breakpoints, with minimum spill, for various small lenght combinations..

(Sorry, i provide no code, but i have a quick and dirty APL function if you want to investigate that area).

**Try to get 8.17' raw material, and you'll save a lot!!** (See the "3 long pieces" header).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment! I really liked the coding you've done to get this answer. It seems the total amount of waste is the same in all cases for my particular issue. I'd like to investigate further and find some other cases where waste can be minimized... I was going to suggest that given the waste be identical, we find the solution with the longest whole waste to be used - but you thought about that too! I'd want to use the leaks ASAP so this could potentially be a huge CPU intensive problem: Say if I have 1000 lumber, how many pieces of racks can I make out of it?

Comment: Actually, i'd re-select the topmost (with a 71" waste piece) as best, since from that you can manufacture both 39"+25" pairs (sum=64") and 34"+30" (sum=64"). Hence you are guaranteed to get the needed 9 pieces from the 71" rest pieces of 4.5 chairs. Just always make either 39+25 or 34+30 from the 71". From 4 lumber you get one chair and 2/9 extra chair, ie. 4 lumber. gives (9/9 + 2/9 = 11/9) chairs. (11/9)*(1000/4) -> 305 chairs from 1000 lumber. Spill will be ca 23" per 4 lumber (=384") -> spill is ca 6 % :-). I doubt you'll be able to decrease that... unless using 8.17' lumber -> 1.5% spill.

Comment: If you want to try with other dimensions, just give the figures. And ofc i can write some pseudocode, but this was just bruteforcedly - all combinations tested. It starts from checking how many of lenght 1 you can make from one lumber, say that is max 3. So alternatives are 0/1/2/3 pieces of lenght 1. Same with others (this is just an example), so in the end try all combs of 0/1/2/3 and 0/1/2/3 and 0/1/2/3/4 and [4th]. Ie. (0,0,0,0, (0,0,0,1), .... (3,3,4,3) pieces of len 34,25,30,30 from 1 lumber. Then a new brute comb of those, to use 4 lumber. Remove impossibles, sort :-)